# Is there a way for html page to loads after retrieving data from ionic storage?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I got an error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

I have a service that retrieves data from the storage and a homepage that calls the service and displays the data.

storage.service.ts

```
async initilizeData() {
   this.data = await this.storage.get('myData')
}
getData() : MyData {
   return this.data
}
```

home.page.ts

```
data: MyData

async ngOnInit() {
   this.storageService.initializeData()
   this.data = this.storageService.getData()
   console.log(this.data)
}
```

home.page.html

```
<ion-text>{{data.name}}</ion-text>
<ion-text>{{data.amount}}</ion-text>
```

The console.log() inside ngOnInit() does log out the data for me but in the HTML page
both data.name and data.amount seems to be undefined (I knew since when I put *ngIf="!data == null" around the code, the error disappeared.)

Thank you for all the answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do that would be to wrap the data using an `ngIf`, like this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="data">
  <ion-text>{{ data.name }}</ion-text>
  <ion-text>{{ data.amount }}</ion-text>
</ng-container>
```

The content won't be displayed until `data` is initialized.

Another way to avoid this would be by using the safe navigation operator, like this:

```
<ion-text>{{ data?.name }}</ion-text>
<ion-text>{{ data?.amount }}</ion-text>
```

In this case, Angular will not try to access `data.name` and `data.amount` if `data` is null or undefined. Please keep in mind that this approach will still render the `ion-text` elements, but they will be empty until `data` is initialized.

Comment: Another thing. Suppose I want to use a getter (from a service) to display data in ion-text tag, will the data be updated when I call a setter from the same service?

Comment: @ChuwongKul the answer depends on how/where/who updates the service, but most of the times it will work as expected and the view will be updated. But a better approach may be to use RxJs like explained in [this blog post](https://www.joshmorony.com/using-behaviorsubject-to-handle-asynchronous-loading-in-ionic/) to have more control over when and how the change is propagated to other components/pages.